# Writing to FireBase using an arithmetic expression

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: This is what my FireBase looks like]

[image: This is what my FireBase looks like]

The user is prompted to convert the earned coins into experience, but I want to use a FireBase entry to verify the user. It is necessary that the user leaves a request for convert. When writing to FireBase, the user specifies the number of coins to be converted. And accordingly, he needs to write them off the balance sheet. The minimum amount to convert is 5000 coins.

Here is the code I am trying to write data to FireBase:

```
public void onClickResetCoin(View view) {
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Resets");
    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            users.child(userID).child("coins").setValue(rescoin);
            int coins = Integer.parseInt(edCoins.getText().toString());
            int ResetCoin = rescoin - coins;
            String resetcoin = String.valueOf(ResetCoin);
            Reset newReset = new Reset(resetcoin);
            mDataBase.push().setValue(newReset);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.
What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you have provided, it seems that you are trying to update the user's coin balance and create a new entry in the "Resets" node to track the user's reset history. However, it is not clear how this code is related to your goal of allowing the user to convert earned coins into experience.

To implement the feature of converting coins into experience, you could follow these steps:

Create a new node in your Firebase database to store conversion requests. For example, you could create a "ConversionRequests" node with the following structure:

ConversionRequests
- Request1
- userId: "user1"
- coinsToConvert: 5000
- Request2
- userId: "user2"
- coinsToConvert: 10000

Modify your app's UI to allow the user to submit a conversion request. You could add a button or a form where the user can enter the number of coins they want to convert and submit the request.

When the user submits a conversion request, write the request data to the "ConversionRequests" node in Firebase using the setValue() method. You can use the FirebaseAuth class to get the currently signed-in user's ID, and then create a new child node under "ConversionRequests" with the request data.

Here's an example code snippet that demonstrates how to write a conversion request to Firebase:

```
FirebaseUser currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String userId = currentUser.getUid();

int coinsToConvert = Integer.parseInt(edCoins.getText().toString());
if (coinsToConvert < 5000) {
    // Handle error: minimum conversion amount is 5000 coins
    return;
}

DatabaseReference conversionRequestsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ConversionRequests");
String requestId = conversionRequestsRef.push().getKey();

ConversionRequest request = new ConversionRequest(userId, coinsToConvert);
conversionRequestsRef.child(requestId).setValue(request);
```

Modify your app's UI to allow the user to submit a conversion request. You could add a button or a form where the user can enter the number of coins they want to convert and submit the request.

When the user submits a conversion request, write the request data to the "ConversionRequests" node in Firebase using the setValue() method. You can use the FirebaseAuth class to get the currently signed-in user's ID, and then create a new child node under "ConversionRequests" with the request data.